# Deleting rows which sum to zero in 1 column but are otherwise duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A001', 'A001', 'A001', 'A002', 'A002', 'A003', 'A003', 'A004', 'A004', 'A004', 'A005', 'A005'],
                   'Val1':[2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7],
                   'Val2':[100, -100, 50, -40, 40, 60, -50, 10, -10, 10, 15, 15]})
```

```
    ID    Val1  Val2
 0  A001     2   100
 1  A001     2  -100
 2  A001     2    50
 3  A002     5   -40
 4  A002     6    40
 5  A003     8    60
 6  A003     8   -50
 7  A004     3    10
 8  A004     3   -10
 9  A004     3    10
10  A005     7    15
11  A005     7    15
```

I want to remove duplicate rows where ID and Val1 are duplicates, and where Val2 sums to zero across two rows. The positive/negative Val2 rows may not be consecutive either, even under a `groupby`

In the above sample data, rows 0 and 1, as well as 7, 8, 9 fulfill these criteria. I'd want to remove [0, 1], and either [7, 8] or [8, 9].

Another constraint here is that there could be entirely duplicate rows ([10, 11]). In this case, I want to keep both rows.

The desired output is thus:

```
    ID    Val1  Val2
 2  A001     2    50
 3  A002     5   -40
 4  A002     6    40
 5  A003     8    60
 6  A003     8   -50
 9  A004     3    10
10  A005     7    15
11  A005     7    15
```

Short of iterating over each row and looking for other rows which fit the criteria, I'm out of ideas for a more "pythonic" way to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put some comments in the code, so hopefully, my line of thought should be clear :

```
cond = df.assign(temp=df.Val2.abs())
# a way to get the same values (differentiated by their sign)
# to follow each other
cond = cond.sort_values(["ID", "Val1", "temp"])

# cumsum should yield a zero for numbers that are different
# only by their sign
cond["check"] = cond.groupby(["ID", "temp"]).Val2.cumsum()
cond["check"] = np.where(cond.check != 0, np.nan, cond.check)

# the backward fill here allows us to assign an identifier
# to the two values that summed to zero
cond["check"] = cond["check"].bfill(limit=1)

# this is where we implement your other condition
# essentially, it looks for rows that are duplicates
# and rows that any two rows sum to zero
cond.loc[
    ~(cond.duplicated(["ID", "Val1"], keep=False) & (cond.check == 0)),
    ["ID", "Val1", "Val2"],
]



     ID Val1    Val2
2   A001    2   50
3   A002    5   -40
4   A002    6   40
6   A003    8   -50
5   A003    8   60
9   A004    3   10
```

Comment: I've added some explanations as well as the additional constraint that if two rows are complete duplicates (rows 10 and 11 in the sample data), they should be kept. Hope that makes it clearer

Comment: I didn't quite follow the logic the first time round so I thought it'd fail for the added constraint that I had edited in, but I tried it and it worked perfected on the sample data that I showed. Trying to validate the results on my actual data but I've marked your answer as correct, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `cumsum` to find which index of `Val2` sums to zero

```
s = df.groupby(['ID', 'Val1']).Val2.cumsum() == 0

n = np.where(s==1)[0]

to_remove = np.concatenate((n, (n-1))) 

new_df = df[~df.index.isin(to_remove)]

new_df 

      ID  Val1  Val2
2   A001     2    50
3   A002     5   -40
4   A002     6    40
5   A003     8    60
6   A003     8   -50
9   A004     3    10
10  A005     7    15
11  A005     7    15
```

Comment: Hi, while your code worked on the sample dataset, I should have mentioned that the positive/negative Val2 rows may not be at the start of the ID-Val1 group, and therefore the cumsum may not be always 0

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
temp = df.groupby('ID')[['Val2']].rolling(2).sum()
ix = temp[temp.Val2==0].index
ar = np.array([x[1] for x in ix.values])
ix2 = ar.tolist() + (ar-1).tolist()
df.drop(ix2, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Val1'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

But this answers refers to your "textual" answer : rows 8 & 9 'Val2' are actually summing to zero (which is not what you the "desired output" you posted)...

Comment: A potential problem is that my dataset is not sorted such that the positive/negative values of Val2 are consecutive. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: @weirdpotatoes yes, if you *can* sort your dataframe before (something like df.sort_values(['ID', 'Val1'], inplace=True) ; but that depends of the way you create your dataset before that...

Comment: I don't think there's a way to sort the dataframe such that the positive and negative Val2s are consecutive, right?

Comment: @weirdpotatoes : you may sort this if you add a temporary column with the absolute value... But if you had duplicates in absolute values (-50, 50, -50), it could have strange effects...

Answer (score 0):

Use `drop_duplicates` method to remove duplicates.

Here is the sample of code:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A001', 'A001', 'A001', 'A002', 'A002', 'A003', 'A003', 'A004', 'A004', 'A004'],
...                    'Val1':[2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3],
...                    'Val2':[100, -100, 50, 40, 45, 60, -50, 10, -10, 10]})
>>> 
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset="Val2", keep= "last", inplace = True)
>>> df
     ID  Val1  Val2
0  A001     2   100
1  A001     2  -100
2  A001     2    50
3  A002     5    40
4  A002     6    45
5  A003     8    60
6  A003     8   -50
8  A004     3   -10
9  A004     3    10
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset="Val1", keep= "last", inplace = True)
>>> df
     ID  Val1  Val2
2  A001     2    50
3  A002     5    40
4  A002     6    45
6  A003     8   -50
9  A004     3    10
>>> ~
```

If you can explain more clearly what does it mean:
`and where Val2 sums to zero across two rows.` ?

This can help you further to get to the full solution.

Comment: I've added some explanations as well as the additional constraint that if two rows are complete duplicates (rows 10 and 11 in the sample data), they should be kept. Hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be a less "brute force" method than this one, but it has the merit of being transparent.

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A001', 'A001', 'A001', 'A002', 'A002', 'A003', 'A003', 'A004', 'A004', 'A004'],
                   'Val1':[2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 3, 3, 3],
                   'Val2':[100, -100, 50, 40, 45, 60, -50, 10, -10, 10]})
df['Val3'] = df['Val2'].abs()
df2        = df.drop_duplicates()
df2        = df.drop(['Val2'], axis = 1)
df3        = df2.drop_duplicates()
result     = pd.merge(df3, df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
results    = result.drop(['ID_x', 'Val1_x', 'Val3_x', 'Val3_y'],axis = 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've edited the question to add the constraint that, if the entire row is duplicated, then I would want to keep them. (See rows 10, 11 in the example above) Hopefully I've made myself clearer.